# What should be the resolution of images in 24ft x 5ft Banner?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

Please tell me the various resolution in different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you may need to provide more information.

There are a few factors, what is the PPI of your image.

e.g, at 72 PPI, your banner would need to be 20736 x 4320. At 300 PPI, your banner would need to be 86400 x 18000

You can use the PPI of your desired image to calculate the pixels at this link http://www.photokaboom.com/photography/learn/printing/1_calculators.htm

Generally speaking, a recent DSLR model (2013+?) on max settings will be good enough without scaling the picture up. but if you are making a banner without images then problem solved, as vectors don't pixellate until you rasterize and export.